# Slim REST API call error with no error message (JQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, rest, slim

I tried to make a GET call from a self written API in javascript (JQuery). I get an error but there is no message included.

Client code looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", 
            url: "APIURL...",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose", "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "crossDomain": "true", "credentials":"include"},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus); //output: error
                console.log(errorThrown); //output: 
            }
        });
    });
```

Also tested this with another url of a REST Test API `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`. This works fine, it outputs the expected data in the success function. So I think the problem is somewhere in my own API.

I made the API with PHP and the [Slim Framework](https://www.slimframework.com/). Code looks like this

```
$app->get ( '/test', function ($request, $response) {
    $data["test"] = "data";
    $json = json_encode ( $data );
    $response->write ( $json );
    return $response;
});
```

This is the called function from my jquery code. In the browser its output is as expected `{"test":"data"}`

The server where my API runs is reachable from the internet. Any solutions or suggestions?

Comment: Check the actual response in the network tab of the console There should at least be a HTTP status code which will help to debug this. Also check the server logs for the error. That should include more useful information

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm getting a Status code 200 OPTIONS but no response content

Comment: If it's making an OPTIONS request then it sounds like this is a cross-domain call. If so you're probably being stopped by the Same Origin Policy and lack of CORS headers in the response. Are you sure there's no errors or warnings in the console about that?

Comment: Getting a error and a warning, but I don't think they are relevenat to the problem `Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead` and `Die Zeichenkodierung des HTML-Dokuments wurde nicht deklariert. Das Dokument wird in manchen Browser-Konfigurationen mit verstümmeltem Text dargestellt, wenn das Dokument Zeichen außerhalb des US-ASCII-Bereichs enthält. Die Zeichenkodierung der Seite muss im Dokument oder Transferprotokoll deklariert werden.`. And there is also `error` from my log.